# Turkish character not showing correctly in hyperref / pdfcomment

Tags: hyperref, languages, characters

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref} % <--
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
\pdftooltip{Turkish Character ıçğöüş İÇĞÖÜŞ}{ıçğöüş İÇĞÖÜŞ}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But when I add `hyperref` line

[image]

is happening. So **ğ/Ğ -> g/G**, **ş/Ş -> s/Ş** and **İ -> I**.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the `unicode=true` key in the `hyperref` load statement (or in `\hypersetup)` in order to allow for unicode characters.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[unicode=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref} % <--
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
\pdftooltip{Turkish Character ıçğöüş İÇĞÖÜŞ}{ıçğöüş İÇĞÖÜŞ}
\end{document}
```